algebraic Cartier divisors vs. analytic Cartier divisors
Suppose $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-variety. Let $X^h$ denote its analytification, so that $(X^h, \mathcal{O}_{X^h})$ is considered as a complex manifold with its sheaf of analytic functions.
One can define algebraic Cartier divisors for $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. Concretely, these are given by the data of $\{ (U_i, f_i) \}$ where $f_i$ are rational functions on Zariski opens $U_i$, and $f_i$ and $f_j$ differ on $U_i \cap U_j$ by a regular function that vanishes nowhere on $U_i \cap U_j$.
On the other hand, one can define analytic Cartier divisors for $(X^h, \mathcal{O}_{X^h})$. These would be given by $\{ (V_i, g_i ) \}$ where $g_i$ is a meromophic function on an analytic open subset $V_i$ and $g_i$ and $ g_j$ differ on $V_i \cap V_j$ by an analytic function that vanishes nowhere on $V_i \cap V_j$.
Certainly, any algebraic Cartier divisor is also an analytic Cartier divisor. But are there analytic Cartier divisors that are not algebraic Cartier divisors? From the definitions presented, this seems like a possibility, but don't algebraic line bundles on $X$ correspond to analytic line bundles on $X^h$?

If $X$ is projective, algebraic and analytic divisors will coincide by Chow's theorem. Otherwise, there are certainly analytic divisors which are not algebraic.

I meant to say "In general, there can certainly be analytic divisors which are not algebraic".


But are there analytic Cartier divisors that are not algebraic Cartier divisors?

Yes those exist, consider for example $X = \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb C}$, so that $X^h = \mathbb C$. Take the holomorphic function $$f(x) = \sin(\pi x).$$
The zero set
$$D = V(f) = \mathbb Z$$
is then an analytic Cartier divisor on $X$. It can not be algebraic though, because it is not Zariski closed!


but don't algebraic line bundles on $X$ correspond to analytic line bundles on $X^h$?

You have two misconceptions here.

Algebraic line bundles on $X$ corrrespond to analytic line bundles on $X^h$ by GAGA for projective varieties.
Cartier divisors are not the same thing as line bundles. In the example above, $f$ is a global holomorphic function, and so its Cartier divisor $D$ gives the trivial line bundle $\mathcal O(D) = \mathcal O$. To see this, cnsider the exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal O \xrightarrow{\cdot f} \mathcal O \to \mathcal O_{D} \to 0,$$ which shows $\mathcal O(-D) \cong \mathcal O$.

